# Are there universal Cognito Ids for AWS regardless of sign in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been wrapping my head around AWS Cognito, and can't seem to find a clear answer on this one.

Here is our situation: I have a react-native mobile application (using `aws-amplify` and it uses three different identity providers:

1. AWS User Pools
2. Facebook
3. Google

I know that user pools are a method to manage, create, and sync users across platforms. Within those user pools, each user has GUID assigned to them called `sub`, short for subject.

I also know that if I use a third party, say Facebook, to sign in, the identity pool will get the third party user, or the user pool, temp access to the AWS services (say dynamo db).

We have another legacy database of previous info, and we want to have a matching process to assign the user to. So, if user1 logs in, they correspond to our old website with user_one in the legacy db, and we want to link up their data and save it for reference later.

**My question is**, in the identity pool that all 3 methods access, is there a universal GUID or ID that I can associate with each user regardless of sign in type, and record in a DB? And how do I get it using react-native?

Here is what I have tried:

```
 Auth.signIn(username, password)
  .then(user => {
   // etc
```

User returns the `user_poolId`, `clientId`, and no identity pool info.

With a federated (FB, Google) sign in:

```
    Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', {
      token: data.accessToken.toString(),
      expires_at: data.expirationTime,
    }, result)
    .then(data => {
      let user = {
        id: data._identityId,
      };
```

This gives me the `_identityId`. I'm hoping to get a value similar to this for the user pool signin.